# Matching values of list type in a Nested Dictionary with certain conditions in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested, match

I'm sorry if this is a stupid question as I'm new to python and coding.
Do ask if there are any doubts in understanding my problem.

I have a nested dictionary as

```
Nested_Dictionary = {0:{'item':['Cat','Dog'],'set':'a'},1:{'item':['Living','Dog'],'set':'b'},2:{'item':['Mouse','Cat'],'set':'c'},3:{'item':['Cat','Dog'],'set':'d'},4:{'item':['Cat','Living'],'set':'e'},5:{'item':['Mouse','Cat'],'set':'f'},6:{'item':['Living','Cat'],'set':'g'},7:{'item':['Pigeon','Living'],'set':'h'},8:{'item':['Cat','Dog'],'set':'i'},9:{'item':['Living','Dog'],'set':'j'},10:{'item':['Mouse','Cat'],'set':'k'},11:{'item':['Living','Living'],'set':'l'}}
```

I want to match the list values in the nested 'item' key and get their upper keys and create a new dictionary with 'item' list values as key and list of all matching elements as their value. The catch is that if 'Living' is in any position in the list 'item', the other position is only used to find the match; and if 'Living' is in both the positions, it's key is appended to all the matches.
The output should be as:

```
{'Cat,Dog':[0,3,8,1,9,4,11], 'Mouse,Cat':[2,5,10,6,11], 'Pigeon,Living':[7,11]}
```

'Pigeon,Living' is unique as Pigeon is there only once. 'Living,Living' is appended to all.

As of now I have been able to match the items once without looking into 'Living' in single position ;and appending the keys with 'Living,Living' in 'item' using this way:

```
compari = defaultdict(list)
for k,v in Nested_Dictionary.items():
    for k1,v1 in v.items():
        if x == 'item':
            compari[v1[0]+','+v1[1]].append(k)   #To match items and append their upper keys
compari = {key:value for key,value in compari.items()}
p=compari.get('Living,Living')                   #To get list of keys in 'Living,Living'
del compari['Living,Living']                     #Deleting the 'Living,Living' key 
for x,y in compari.items():
    compari[x].append(p)              #appending list of keys in 'Living,Living' to all elements
print(compari)
```

I'm getting the output as:

```
{'Cat,Dog': [0,3,8,11], 'Living,Dog': [1,9,11], 'Mouse,Cat': [2,5,10,11], 'Cat,Living': [4,11], 'Living,Cat': [6,11], 'Pigeon,Living': [7,11]}
```

I'm stuck at comparing and finding the matches where only one position of the item list is 'Living' where I have to find the match based on the other position. Also suggest if there is any better way of doing what I have already done. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `collections.defaultdict` to store the running matching and original dictionary keys. This answer breaks up the input into specific groups based on the `item` content: complete `item` values are saved in `full`, and any `item` with at least one `Living` goes in `p`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
Nested_Dictionary = {0:{'item':['Cat','Dog'],'set':'a'},1:{'item':['Living','Dog'],'set':'b'},2:{'item':['Mouse','Cat'],'set':'c'},3:{'item':['Cat','Dog'],'set':'d'},4:{'item':['Cat','Living'],'set':'e'},5:{'item':['Mouse','Cat'],'set':'f'},6:{'item':['Living','Cat'],'set':'g'},7:{'item':['Pigeon','Living'],'set':'h'},8:{'item':['Cat','Dog'],'set':'i'},9:{'item':['Living','Dog'],'set':'j'},10:{'item':['Mouse','Cat'],'set':'k'},11:{'item':['Living','Living'],'set':'l'}}
d, full, p = defaultdict(list), set(), {'partial':set(), 'full':set()}
#separate complete `item`s from those that have "Living"
for a, b in Nested_Dictionary.items():
   if 'Living' in b['item']:
      p['full' if sum(i == 'Living' for i in b['item']) == 2 else 'partial'].add((a, tuple(b['item'])))
   else:
      d[(x:=tuple(b['item']))].append(a)
      full.add(x)

#match `item`s that have any partial occurrences of "Living"
for v, i in p['partial']:
   if (m:=[b for b in full if any(j == k for j, k in zip(i, b))]):
      for x in m:
         d[x].append(v)
   else:
      d[i].append(v)
      full.add(i)

#update `d` with key value of any `item`s that just have "Living"
for v, i in p['full']:
   for x in full:
      d[x].append(v)

print({','.join(a):b for a, b in d.items()})
```

Output:

```
{'Cat,Dog': [0, 3, 8, 1, 4, 9, 11], 'Mouse,Cat': [2, 5, 10, 6, 11], 'Pigeon,Living': [7, 11]}
```